# HTML5/JS - A good game engine which doesn't rely on Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, game-engine

I'm looking to build an RTS game built mainly in HTML/CSS. There would be a map, but I am unsure if to build it in Canvas or some other way.

The map needs to stretch out for different window sizes, so I was thinking maybe SVG.

I've literally found a ton of game engines, but they seem to mainly rely on canvas.

I guess my main priorities are:

- sound
- frame limiting
- time traversal
- AI

I'm looking for a game engine library to use in Javascript that lets me render DOM elements and not just canvas elements.

Comment: What's wrong with using a canvas? You'd be hard pressed to write a bespoke game without a canvas, let alone a generic game engine

Comment: @Bojangles there are many UI elements and I find them a lot easier to create using CSS3. Especially as it needs to be fluid and match different window resolutions.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Crafty game engine](http://craftyjs.com/). It lets you choose between canvas and DOM rendering. And it got lots of other good stuff.

Answer (score 0):

BabylonJS is the best gaming engine right now. It supports geometry instancing which provides good performance to render large amounts of units on screen. Plus it comes with its own physics engine, supports WebGL, imports Blender models and ton of other great features.
http://www.babylonjs.com/

Comment: How  does Babylon compare with Three JS? I found that Three JS is more documented.

Comment: @xmxmxmx Babylon documentation is great. There playground site has a ton of examples too. https://www.babylonjs-playground.com/